# Compare two objects in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I compare two generic objects. Below is sample code of doing a comparison and this line elem > value throws an error saying `Could not find overload for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments`

```
func index<T : Equatable>(array: T[], value: T) -> Int {
    for (index, elem) in enumerate(array) {
        if elem > value {
            return index
        }
    }
    return array.count
}
```

Comment: Neither Equatable nor Comparable protocols means that *operator >* needs to be provided.  Comparable needs *operator <* however.

Comment: Another, in SWIFT, remembering inherited from :NSObject if you want to use ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Comparable, not Equatable. Equatable only has `==`.

Comment: So changing "Equatable" with "Comparable" will solve his issues?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I think so. I can't try it right now. Am I mistaken? I just double-checked the Comparable docs and they say it should work.

Comment: Doesn't the Comparable protocol require `operator <` and not `operator >`?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes, it requires you to write `<`, but since you can deduce `>`, `<=` and `>=` just by knowing `==` and `<`, there are apparently default implementations of the other three comparison functions for Comparable.

Answer (score 7):

From the Swift Reference:

> The Equatable protocol makes it possible to determine whether two values of the same type are considered to be equal.
>
> There is one required operator overload defined in the protocol: ==.

There is no guarantee that `Equatable` objects have to implement the `>` operator, which explains your error.

Take a look at [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Comparable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH16-SW1) however. Notice that comparable only needs to overload the `<` and `==` operators.

However, if not `a < b` nor is `a == b`, you can assume that `a > b`.